# Cannot establish connection to MySQL using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using Kubuntu 13.10 with Java 8 and Netbeans 8.2.0 and MariaDB (MySQL) as my database. I would like to learn Hibernate. I created empty Java project and added some libs:

[image]

Here's my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

[image]

And I'm getting this strange error  when I try to create a new "Hibernate Mapping Wizard":

[image]

Which does not mean much to me, since I just started with Java and databases. Why such info? What does derby has to do with my application? I mean, I would like to use mysql as my database, not derby.

I've added:

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
export CLASSPATH
```

to my `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following URL and download derby driver and add this driver jar file in your application library folder.

[Download Driver Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/derbyclient/derbyclient.jar.zip)

Comment: What file have you added in your project library zip or jar?